# Random.choice isn't working

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using random.choice with a dictionary but it doesn't work. This error is displayed as
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'choice' on line 90 in main.py

(made the classes before hand)

```
items = {"Weak Leather Boots": Item("Weak Leather Boots", 1, "Armour"),"Health Potion":Item("Health Potion", 5, "Medicine" ), "Iron Fist":Item("Iron Fist" , 5, "Weapon"), "Speed Shoes":Item("Speed Shoes", 10, "Armour"),"Gold":randint(1, 50), "Ice Wand":Item("Ice Wand", 20, "Weapon") }
def Loot(lvl):
  choose = random(items.values())

  if choose.rarity > lvl:
    choose = randint(items.values())

  else:
    print "You have found a " + choose.name
    if type(choose) is int:
        player.gold += choose

    else:
        player.inventory.append(choose.name)
```

Comment: You don't appear to be using `random.choice` in the code you've pasted. But, the first guess would be that you've called a function `random` somewhere, and overwritten the reference to the module

Comment: This problem cannot be reproduced because you don't show us how you import the `random` module or how you call `random.choice`. You should be able to write a small example program of just a few lines that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the beginning of your code you should import random

```
import random
```

and then call it like this:

```
random.randint(something)
```

or:

```
random.choice(something)
```

or if you want to you can import only randint and choice:

```
from random import randint,choice
```

and then you can just write:

```
randint(something)
choice(something)
```

if you want to learn more on random module this is the link for documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html